# Understanding why extracted contours offset in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am a beginner at QGIS, and I am trying to extract 1m contours from 5m DEM data. I have clipped a small area from the DEM data (roughly 1.2km by 1.2km). When I go to Raster - Extraction - Contour, it gives the correct contours, but they are offset on the map by about 1km to the west, and about 140m to the south. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Does the DEM have a projection?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that out...very new at this

Comment: Go to Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Information then select the DEM and see what projection it has?

Comment: The "Raster info" box is blank. The bottom box says gdalinfo and then the file location on my computer is in quotation marks. Should there be something is the raster info box?

Comment: In the 'Input file' select the DEM file, if it is not already selected. If you can see in the gdalinfo the name of the DEM file, then just press OK and you should get the information of the DEM file including the Coordinate System used.

Answer (score 2):

That definitely sounds as a **coordinate reference system** (**CRS**, projection) issue. Contours are created in different CRS than the grid is as ahmadhanb suggested.

There is important basic rule in QGIS - **you always have to be aware of source CRS of datasets and project CRS (displayed map)**. Most if not all the tools in QGIS won't reproject on the fly as map window does.

1. Double click on raster layer name and in General tab there is "Coordinate reference system". Make sure it is the right one you are supposed to use.
2. If you double click on your contour file there should be the same CRS. If not, your contours are in wrong projection.

You can switch it there on the fly to the same projection as raster is to check that fix your issue. *But be aware that is only changing the projection on the fly* and not changing projection of the contour file.

If you want to set the new (correct) projection to contours you need to go to the menu **Vector / Data Management Tools / Define Current Projection...** choose the contour file and projection (might be needed to click on *Choose* button to get what you need).

Comment: Thanks for this. I have followed those steps, and now have my contours and the hdrclip in EPSG:28350 GDA94/MGA Zone 50, and the contours are still offset from the hdrclip by the same amount. Have you got any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: @Emily Did you check if the clipped DEM lines up with the original DEM?

Comment: Yes, they do line up, and they line up with the road map I have underneath. The contours are the only thing not lining up properly.

Comment: What is your project EPSG? (right bottom corner)?

Comment: EPSG:4326 (OTF). Should this be the same as above?

Comment: I just wonder about that distance, even if there is mismatch with GDA94 and AGD84 or AGD66 it shouldn't be 1km to west... Yes, please set the project EPSG to the same. You might have switched off on the fly reprojection...

Comment: Switching the project EPSG to 28350 has caused the contours and hdr data to align, however they have rotated about 30 degrees, and are now offset from my WMS layer underneath...

Comment: When you double click on the right bottom EPSG code and get to Project CRS, do you have checked the first box 'Enable on the fly' CRS transformation? I would start assuring myself that the DEM I work with is really in 28350 (comparing to some layer I am 100% sure it is in the right location). If it is, I would make sure that the project is in the same EPSG and on the fly reprojection is set on. Then recreate the contours.